# Confused about the role of the coefficient group in cohomology?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Forgive me if this is a rather simple question, since I suspect Hatcher does cover it at some point but it's not at all obvious to me why some of what he does is valid without mentioning it. So suppose I have some chain complex
$$ \cdots \xrightarrow{\partial} C_{n+1} \xrightarrow{\partial} C_{n} \xrightarrow{\partial} C_{n-1} \xrightarrow{\partial} \cdots \xrightarrow{\partial} C_{0} \xrightarrow{\partial} 0$$
I am perfectly comfortable with defining the cohomology groups as the homology groups of the dualized complex
$$ G \xrightarrow{\delta} Hom \left(C_{0}, G \right) \xrightarrow{\delta} Hom \left(C_{1}, G \right) \xrightarrow{\delta} \cdots \xrightarrow{\delta} Hom \left( C_{n}, G \right) \xrightarrow{\delta} \cdots$$
Now my question is, what difference does it make what group I choose as the coefficients? Surely this can be replaced by any abelian group. Certainly Hatcher seems to use $\mathbb{Z}$ as this group, while for de Rham cohomology the group seems to be $\mathbb{R}$. Surely the choice of coefficient group makes a big difference. As I said I'm sure this is a very simple question, but it seems odd to me that Hatcher swaps between $\mathbb{Z}$ and $G$ in $\S 3.1$ without any mention of this and I have found the Universal Coefficient Theorem, but I'm having trouble interpreting how exactly it answers my question. Have I missed something obvious? Any help is appreciated

Thanks.

Comment: It's unclear to me what exactly you're asking. It's convenient to be able to use any abelian group for various computations. In practice people use rings such as $\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{C}$, and $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ to extract or ignore various kinds of information as appropriate. Exactly what information is covered by the universal coefficient theorem.

Comment: @Luke: I don't know whether this is what you have in mind  - but different coeffs turn up in practice - e.g., if one has $F\to E \to B$ is a fibration, the (co)-homology of $E$ can be expressed in terms of those of $B$ with coeff's of that of $F$ (Serre spectral sequence). There are also theorems that compare etale coh with   sing coh with coeffs in finite groups (none with $\mathbb Z$, for ex, because the Gal group is endowed with the profinite top). I am sure topologists have good examples - you might look up Bockstein; I am not competent to say anything serious on this... hope this helps!

Comment: There are also variants on de Rham coho (e.g., in complex an/alg. top); more gen.. there  is also coh of sheaves (on the spaces of interest), and even variants on sheaves - things that show up 'in practice'. OK?